# Binding multiple checkboxes to a binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, checkbox, datasource

I have a program and a form whereby I have multiple checkboxes bound to a datasource. 
I simply created this by dragging the details from the datasource and dropping the checkboxes onto the form.

[image]

At the top of the form I have a binding navigator that includes a save button. The code for the save button:

```
 private void earndeductmasterBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.earndeductmasterBindingSource.EndEdit();

                this.earndeductmasterTableAdapter.Update(this.eko_payrollDataSet.earndeductmaster);
                this.eko_payrollDataSet.earndeductmaster.AcceptChanges();
                this.earndeductmasterTableAdapter.Fill(this.eko_payrollDataSet.earndeductmaster);

                MessageBox.Show("Earning/Deduction details updated successfully");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I am able to add/delete/update records correctly except when it comes to the check-boxes. E.g. If I check the advance checkbox and click on Save, the recurrence type checkbox will automatically get checked, and vice versa.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this binding each checkbox manually. e.g.

```
cbRecurrence.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", earndeductmasterBindingSource, "recurrenceType", true));
```